# How do I add a file to a UWP application's resource?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, uwp

I am new to Windows Universal Apps and wanted to add an XML-file to my project's resources. In WinForms, I can add a resource file to the project and then add files to this resource. But how do I do that in UWP?

I added a .resw resource file, but I could **only** add Strings :(

And I have another question about UWP. In WinForms, I can update the UI by calling the Update()-Method. How do I do this in UWP? In my app, I'm dynamically setting a lable's and four button's text and I need to update / refresh the UI.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: To the second part of your question: For updating the ui when changing properties in the code you can use `Data Binding` and the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. Take a look at the `MVVM` pattern: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnshews_blog/2015/09/09/a-minimal-mvvm-uwp-app/

Answer (score -1):

UWP has a different mechanism for loading files or resrouces.

> In WinForms, I can add a resource file to the project and then add files to this resource. But how do I do that in UWP?

In UWP, the resource file is used for string content. For details please see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/globalizing/put-ui-strings-into-resources). And the file resource you mentioned can be done like described in this article: [How to load file resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965322(v=win.10)) 
We have serval ways like:

- You can just begin a URI with a "/" to refer to the package root. For example: `<img src="/file.png" alt="" />`
- You can use the "ms-appx:///" protocol. For example:`<img src="ms-appx://packageFullName/file.png" alt="" />`
- You can also omit the package name to let the system fill in the domain, as shown here: `<img src="ms-appx:///file.png" alt="" />`

The above is the way for you to access directly from UI.

To access the file from code behind, you can try the following: Like WinForm, when you set your xml file as the content file, the xml file will be copied to the installed location of a UWP app. To access and use this xml file you can use Package class As Jayden mentioned above. Use the [InstalledLocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.package) of package and then use GetFileAsync to get that file.
If you still want to use uri in code behind, you can use [GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile#Windows_Storage_StorageFile_GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync_Windows_Foundation_Uri_)

***Note: We only have read permission in installed location***

By the way, for updating the UI. Matthias has already mentioned  binding. It is the common way for us to update the data between UI and the source.